# Image uploading not working with Multipart

Tags: android, android-studio, http-post, multipartentity

Below is requesting parameters what I tried with postman and is working fine

[image: Postman request Parameter]

However, I am not able to do the same pragmatically from Android.

Below is what I tried

```
File urls= new File(fn)

Part[] parts = new Part[1];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
try {
      parts[i] = new FilePart("image", urls);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(parts,httpPost.getParams());
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

would appreciate the solution

Comment: There isn't really enough code there to see what you're trying and no description of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Android Upload Service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) library. 
I have used it several times in my organization's production apps without fail.

Steps to follow (as shown on [Github Wiki](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki)) -

1) [Setup](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Setup)

2) [Multi-part Upload Example](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/wiki/Recipes)

Below is the recipe for quick review -

```
public void uploadMultipart(final Context context) {
    try {
        String uploadId =
          new MultipartUploadRequest(context, "http://upload.server.com/path")
            // starting from 3.1+, you can also use content:// URI string instead of absolute file
            .addFileToUpload("/absolute/path/to/your/file", "your-param-name")
            .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
            .setMaxRetries(2)
            .startUpload();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e("AndroidUploadService", exc.getMessage(), exc);
    }
}
```